# Substract pandas Dataframes with different indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two `pandas` dataframes which I would like to substract. The base dataframe `minuend` has more indices and columns than the other dataframe `subtrahend`.

They are defined as following:

```py
minuend = pd.DataFrame(
    {"angles": [0, 3, 4], "degrees": [360, 180, 360]},
    index=["circle", "triangle", "rectangle"],
)

           angles  degrees
circle          0      360
triangle        3      180
rectangle       4      360
```

```py
subtrahend = pd.Series(
    [1, 1], index=["circle", "triangle"], name="angles"
).to_frame()

          angles
circle         1
triangle       1
```

The expected result is:

```
           angles  degrees
circle         -1      360
triangle        3      180
rectangle       3      360
```

**What is the best way to achive this** since `minuend - subtrahend` or `minuend.sub(subtrahend_df)` does not work out of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.update`:

```
minuend.update(minuend.sub(subtrahend))
```

Output:

```
           angles  degrees
circle       -1.0      360
triangle      2.0      180
rectangle     4.0      360
```

Comment: I think this is quite readable and I like it. It is not the fastest according to `%timeit` but it is not relevant I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`df.subtract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.subtract.html) with [`df.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
In [1396]: minuend.subtract(subtrahend).fillna(minuend).astype(int)
Out[1396]: 
           angles  degrees
circle         -1      360
rectangle       4      360
triangle        2      180
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I works like a charm. It is similar to @jezrael approach but more readable in my point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fill_value=0` parameter in [`DataFrame.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html):

```
df = minuend.sub(subtrahend, fill_value=0).astype(int)
print (df)
           angles  degrees
circle         -1      360
rectangle       4      360
triangle        2      180
```

Comment: This approach is the most performant according to `%timeit` although for me the usage of `fill_value` is not self-explanatory. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

A solution I came up with is:

```
minuend.loc[subtrahend.index, subtrahend.columns] -= subtrahend
```

But I am not sure whether this is the most pythonic and efficient way to solve it.

What do you think?